# Adding Third party library to Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, payment

I have an RSA algorithm Library giving to me by a payment gateway and When I do a

```
include (app_path().'/PaymentGateway/Crypt/RSA.php');
```

this and try to make an object as `$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();` this it gives me and error saying

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Crypt_RSA' not found
```

I tried including it in `web.php` and making an object it worked the problem occur when I try to include it in a Controller.

Comment: Try to psr-autoload it in the composer.json.

Comment: would be kind enough to explain that please?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did. Oh and a little back ground I use to have this in Laravel 4, PHP 5, jpgraph 2.

I am using `jpgraph 4.1` on `Laravel 5.5` using `PHP 7`.

1. Created a folder under app called `jpgraph`
2. Placed the `src` folder that is in the tarball of jpgraph in that folder
3. Created file call `Graph1.php`, is my code using jpgraph,  with the class `Custom_GraphsJM` in the `jpgraph` folder.
4. In `composer.json` added `"app/jpgraph/Graph1.php"` to the `"classmap"`

   ```
   "autoload": {
     "classmap": [
       "database/seeds",
       "database/factories",
       "app/jpgraph/Graph1.php"
     ],
     "psr-4": {
       "App\\": "app/"
     }
   },
   ```
5. In the application folder:

   `composer dump-autoload`
6. Checked the `autoload_classmap.php` and I have

   `'Custom_GraphsJM' => $baseDir . '/app/jpgraph/Graph1.php',`
7. In my Model at the top I have

   `use Custom_GraphsJM;`
8. To create a class

   `$Two_Graphs_Temp = new Custom_GraphsJM();`

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Composer to autoload any (non-PSR) class by adding the base folder to:

```
"autoload": {
"classmap": [
    "app/commands",
    "app/database/migrations",
    "app/database/seeds",
    "app/tests/TestCase.php"
],
....
```

And you can also autoload autoloaders by adding them to the files section:

```
"autoload": {
"files": [
    "temboo/src/Temboo_Loader.php"
],
```

...

After adding those entries, execute:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

And check the file vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php, the available classes must be all listed in it, if one file is not there it will not be autoloaded.

Answer (score 0):

On default, everything included in the app folder of your laravel project is autoloaded, that is described in the **composer.json** of your project:

```
...        
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
...
```

The only thing you will need to do is simply **use** the namespace:

```
use App/Path/To/Third/Party/plugin/Class;
```

If, however, the plugin is placed outside of the scope of App, then simply add it to the psr-4 autoloader:

```
    "psr-4": {
        "ProjectRootNs\\": "projects/myproject/"
    }
```