# How to use php extension in Laravel Controller which has no laravel syntaxes

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have written a php extension named "sum" to be used with Laravel on ubuntu 18.04 system.

file "sum.so" is stored at "/usr/lib/php/20170718/"
file "sum.ini" are stored at  "/etc/php/7.2/mods-available"

I have sum.php file with following content:

```
<?php
    $arr = [10,20,30,40];
    $sum_total = sum($arr);
    echo "Sum Total: " . $sum_total;
?>
```

I am able to call sum.php from anywhere, correctly with answer "Sum Total: 100"
But it gives following error::

> "Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to undefined function sum()"

when I call it from Laravel controller index() function.

Comment: User Absolute path and add your path to `classmap` in `composer.json`. For more details check this question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44925824/adding-third-party-library-to-laravel

Comment: If it doesn't work then search on google how to implement third party libraries in laravel. It'll give you answer to your question

Comment: One more thing sum.php is written in php not in c/c++.